# Use the comparison test to find whether $\int_0^\infty 1/(x^2+1)^2\,dx$ converges or not

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was thinking what function I should compare it to. If I say whether a function is smaller or bigger than this one, then I must prove that. I was thinking of (x+1)^2 but I realized that this converges so that won't prove the integral diverges. So, what function should I use?

Comment: But the integral converges - to show this, you want to prove that a function that bounds it from above converges.

Comment: (without having a problem itself at $ \ x = 0 \ $ -- I had to delete a suggested integrand because its integral doesn't converge near the $ \ y-$ axis)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner if you wrote an answer, please undelete it, I would still like to look at it...

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish if it does, then I want to prove that it does..

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: You could salvage your answer by using your comparison to bound $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and the constant $1$ as a bound on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I revised my answer completely -- the "easy" integral I was going to suggest wouldn't work because I missed that we are starting at $ \ x = 0 \ $ ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, true enough (since my current answer is a different sort of "patch job" anyway).  Thank you, I'll add that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: we have $(x^2+1)^2\geq (x^2+1)$ so
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\ \text{d}x \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)}\ \text{d}x
$$
This last integral is a well-known one.

Comment: Can you prove that first inequality?

Comment: @TanMath: That proof is very easy; have you tried?

Comment: @TanMath. $(x^2+1)^2- (x^2+1)=x^2+x^4$ could be sufficient.

Comment: @TanMath Since $x^2 + 1 \geq 1$ we get $(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 1)\geq (x^2 + 1)\cdot 1 $.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the function you proposed, $ \ \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \ $ will work, since it is larger than the  integrand $ \ \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2} \ $ over $ \ ( 1, \ \infty) \ $ and the region bounded by the two functions over $ \ [0, \ 1 ] \ $ is finite.  (You will need to demonstrate both of these statements are true.)  So the given improper integral is convergent.

**Brian M. Scott** in his comment proposed this fix for the function I was originally going to suggest.  We can show that $ \ \frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)^2} \ $ is smaller than the piecewise-defined function $ \ f(x) \ = \ 1 \ \ \text{for}    \ \ 0 \ \le \ x \ \le \ 1 \ $ , $ \ \frac{1}{x^4} \ \ \text{for} \ \ x \ > \ 1 \ $ .  The integral for $ \ f(x) \ $ is certainly convergent over $ \ [ 0, \ \infty) \ $ (the section over $ \ [ 1, \ \infty) \ $ by " $ \ p-$ test " ).

Answer (score 2):

Split the integral into
$\int_0^1 + \int_1^{\infty}
$.

For the first integral,
the function is less than 1,
so the integral is also
less than 1.

For the second integral,
the function is less than
$1/x^2$,
and the integral of this
from 1 to $\infty$
is 1.